# how to increment date by giving the number of days in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to increment dates using JavaScript I used `.setDate(1)` to increment dates by one day
but if the date is `31/11/2011` after increment becomes `1/0/2012`,

the question is how to increment date by giving the number of days .

js

```
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+1);
    alert(newDate.getFullYear()+"-"+newDate.getMonth()+"-"+newDate.getDate());
```

Comment: Just use `+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+

Comment: Your question should read "Why is my month index off by one, in Javascript?", or similar, since that is both the error you're asking about, and the accepted solution.

As a question about adding days to a date, this question and the answers below are a bit too obtuse for a newcomer to javascript to learn from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, because in javascript, months are indexed from 0, not 1.

You need to alert like this instead:

```
alert(newDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+newDate.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not wrong, given that months in Javascript dates range from 0 to 11. So when you speak of `31/11/2011`, what javascript understands is `31/12/2011`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it some more clear:

```
var Date = new Date();
var DaysToAdd = 6;
someDate.setDate(Date.getDate() + DaysToAdd);
```

Formatting Date to dd/mm/yyyy format:

```
var dd = Date.getDate();
var mm = Date.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = Date.getFullYear();

var NewDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ yyyy;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure why you've called a variable Date, which is the same name as the function Date()  ...confusing.   Also not sure where someDate came from ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this, Suppose you want to increment current date by 2 days then,

```
var today = new Date(); // Or Date.today()
var newDate = today.add(2).day();
```

Comment: `add()` is not a javascript function. you may have got working using external library here.